# Postfix configure a gateway to outbound emails

Tags: postfix, ip, gateway

I have a server configured with Postfix in my business office. I have another server at a hosting provider that I want to send all my outbound mail through. How can I do this. The only way I know its mounting all the filesystem with NFS.

Answer (score 4):

You'll use the `relayhost` option in main.cf in your office email server. E.g.

```
relayhost = mailserver.amazingvps.com:25
```

You probably also want to use `smtp_use_tls=yes` and `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes` when logging in to your VPS relayhost. Open relays are bad, mmkay?

Comment: Its so easy. And what about the DNS. How shoild i congifure?. The MX register should i put the office server or vps?. In other words, when a mail arrives at the VPS its redirects automatically to office server.

Comment: Your mx record should point to the server that initially gets the email, so it sounds like the VPS. @Marcos